# Prevent local storage from being changed when filtering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Whenever I dispatch a search action using context and `useReducer` for an object in an array stored in local storage, it returns the object, but when I delete the search query from the input box, the list is not returned, and the page is blank, can anyone help please?

This is my context:

```
const NotesContext = createContext(null);
const NotesDispatchContext = createContext(null);

const getStoredNotes = (initialNotes = InitialNotes) => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedNotes")) || initialNotes;
};

export const NotesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [NOTES, dispatch] = useReducer(NotesReducer, getStoredNotes());
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("storedNotes", JSON.stringify(NOTES));
  }, [NOTES]);

  return (
    <NotesContext.Provider value={NOTES}>
      <NotesDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </NotesDispatchContext.Provider>
    </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useNotesContext = () => {
  return useContext(NotesContext);
};
export const useNotesDispatchContext = () => {
  return useContext(NotesDispatchContext);
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useNotesDispatchContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query.length !== 0) {
      dispatch({
        type: "searchNotes",
        query: query,
      });
    }
  }, [query]);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <header>
        <Title title={"Notes"} className={"app_title"} />
        <form className="search_container">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
          <input
            type="search"
            placeholder="search notes"
            value={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          />
        </form>
      </header>
```

This is my reducer function

```
case "searchNotes": {
      [...NOTES].filter((note) =>
        note.title.toLowerCase().includes(action.query)
      );
    }
```

The function seems to actually remove the all data from the local storage instead of filtering based on the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

When you dispatch `searchNotes`, you are changing `NOTES`, and the blow `useEffect` runs. So if the filter resulted in an empty array, there would be nothing in `localStorage`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("storedNotes", JSON.stringify(NOTES));
}, [NOTES]);
```

## Solution

What you can do is to remove that `useEffect` in `App` that has `query` as a dependency and dispatches `searchNotes`. And filter directly in the JSX while rendering. Something like this:

```js
{
  NOTES.filter((note) => note.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)).map((note, index) => (
    <div key={index}>{note.title}</div>
  ))
}
```

This way, `NOTES` is not mutated while having a working search. And at this point, you can remove the `searchNotes` case from your reducer.

Comment: Alright, concise and amazing 